# Http Request doesn't give correct response

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a http request and get the full page as string.

After I got response, I'm trying to find the position of a substring in it.

But I can't find that substring in the response whereas the original web page contains that substring in Google Chrome -> View Source. (Checked in mobile version).

So, my guesses are:

**1) Maybe It's not requesting the mobile version of that web page? If it is so, how can I change my user agent to a mobile version? like chrome android?**

**2) Is it possible that response does not give me the full page? Because, when I try, LogCat isn't showing the full page.**

Thanks.

Comment: did you display the response in your app to see if you get anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-defaulthttpclientandroidhttpclient-and-httpparams/ this will help you for changing user agent.

2) for logging try to log your response like Log.d("Reponse is: ", response);

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you can set the user agent by creating your client like this:

```
HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("MyAppUserAgent/1.0");
```

2) You would need to post the code, but logcat will not necessarily dump the entire response. There is maximum length per log and text is clipped to that length.

Comment: Apparently my answer didn't help you. I'm not sure what you are asking me now